# How to achieve 100 000 users concurrent connectivity to sql server database?

Tags: sql-server

How to achieve 100 000 users concurrent connectivity to sql server database?

I have a scenario where 100 000 users will login to the website which is using sql server as backend to perform insert on the same table. Is it practical? How to achieve it? How should one design the database?

Comment: I doubt you'll have 100.000 concurrent connections to the database; even if you somehow manage to have 100.000 concurrent users to your website.

Comment: If you really have 100 000 concurrent users, you probably should hire an expert, instead of asking on the internet.

Comment: that is huge. Youtube gets an average of 30 millions users per day with average of 40 min watching. that's around 800,000 concurrent user. You do need an expert company since you are 1/8 of youtube size service. that's impressive.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can handle very large number of users inserting rows. What will happen is users will connect, their identity will be checked if they can connect and if they have the correct privileges and then the insert will happen and SQL Server will then drop the connection. There is no reason for a user to maintain a connection once the insert has happened and SQL Server has returned a status code indicating success or failure.

I have had success with very large number of users doing this to a single audit table and I have had to have the audit table be a heap without any keys. This way SQL Server would just add consecutive rows to consecutive pages and this happened fast enough for the inserts to successfully happen. There is no guarantee that the inserts will occur in this fashion (but in practice they did) and it handled very high volumes of data. You of course have to test to see if your install can handle the volume you anticipate. It does not matter what order the data is stored as long as it is successfully saved.

I have never seen an install that can handle 100,000 active sessions. The number of locks would probably overwhelm any conceivable set of hardware. You may also want to do a select @@MAX_CONNECTIONS from the intended machine that will indicate, as the number returned will indicate the maximum number of simultaneous connections the current instance can (theoretically) handle. On both SQL Server 2008 and 2012 enterprise the number returned is 32,767.